# Doesn't VirtualBox 4.0 support drag-drop file copy yet?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware

> Version 4.0.0 will be new major release. The following major new features were added:
>   -New settings/disk file layout for VM portability; see the manual for more information.
>   -Open Virtualization Format Archive (OVA) support; see the manual for more information.
>   -VMM: support more than 1.5/2 GB guest RAM on 32-bit hosts
>   -Language bindings: uniform Java bindings for both local (COM/XPCOM) and remote (SOAP) -invocation APIs
>   -Chipset: added support for the Intel ICH9 chipset with 3 PCI buses, PCI express and -Message Signaled Interrupts (MSI)
>   -Audio: Intel HD Audio is now available as guest hardware, for better support with modern -guest operating systems (e.g. 64-bit Windows; bug #2785).
>   -GUI: redesigned user interface with guest window preview
>   -GUI: new display mode with downscaled guest display
>   -Resource control: added support for limiting a VM's CPU time and IO bandwidth.
>   -Storage: support asynchronous I/O for iSCSI, VMDK, VHD and Parallels images
>   -Storage: support for resizing VDI and VHD images
>   -Windows Additions: support for automatically updating the Guest Additions (requires -installed Windows Guest Additions 4.0 or later)
>   **-Guest Additions: support for copying files into the guest file system**

What does the last line mean?
I thought this is a drag-drop file copy feature like VMWare.
I tried that. But I couldn't copy by drag-drop, ctrl-c ctrl-v either.

Edit:
I mean VBox 4.0 beta, not 3.x
The release note is [here](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=36748).
Download link is [here](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.0.0_BETA1/).

Answer (score 3):

No, the current versions of VirtualBox (3.x) do not support file drag'n'drop between the host and the guest.

There is no additional information in the 4.0 [release notes](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=36748) but it seems that they finally are implementing this feature.

Comment: I've already installed and used it. But it didn't work. You mean, in the official version(not beta), will the feature be shipped? I hope so.

Answer (score 2):

This won't work without the guest additions installed, and possibly you will need the Oracle VM Extension Pack installed as well (though I am not sure). Did you install all the extra goodies? Is this a brand-new installed-from-scratch virtual machine (what OS for host and guest) or is it one you already had available?

While this is still early in the public beta (have you tried [beta 3](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=37074) yet?), it is possible they haven't even turned on the feature yet. Have you tried asking your question in the [official beta feedback forum](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewforum.php?f=15), you might have better success there.

Comment: I have 4.1.8 with guest additions and the extension pack.  Windows XP guest on a Windows XP host.  Neither drag and drop file copy nor ctrl+c, ctrl+v work for copying files.

Answer (score 2):

**Experimental drag and dropping** between the Host and Guest is supposed to be enabled since version 4.2 of Virtualbox which is still in development. Currently **RC3** is available.

You will need the latest Virtualbox Tools installed inside the Guest.

Cheers!

For the track record of Virtualbox DnD see [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/81).

Answer (score 1):

I think so, just installed VirtualBox 4.0, tried and checked the manual, no support for file drag-and-drop between the host and guest yet.